# Sharepoint  Infopath Forms 2007-Views Filtering 

Tags: 2007, infopath, list-view

I have an InfoPath form in SharePoint 2007, which takes date as input for one of the controls. I want to display the InfoPath form items in different views.

In one view I need to display the records which are due to expire in the next 6 months.

How do I specify the condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the date promoted to a Sharepoint field?  If so, create a view with the data you want and set the filter to be Your Date Column is less than or equal to [Today]+180.